# React TypeScript, cant use context to change canvas

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas

The canvas renders at the correct size but the canvas is never filled blue, I don't understand why?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  console.log('this prints just fine');
  const canvasWidth = 820;
  const canvasHeight = 620;
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  console.log(canvasRef.current) // null
  if (canvasRef.current) {
    console.log('this never prints!!');
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (ctx) {
      console.log('this never prints!!');
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      canvas.width = canvasWidth;
      canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    }

  }
  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={canvasWidth}
      height={canvasHeight}
    >
    </canvas>
  );
};

export { App };
```

UPDATE

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const canvasWidth = 820;
  const canvasHeight = 620;
  useEffect(() => {
...
```

The above fixed the issue

Comment: I think you should be doing context fill in componentDidMount or in useEffect Hook. Since canvas has not render while initializing the component, hence it canvas context must be null or undefined.

Comment: useEffect got it, thank you!